# GPIO conditional in python

Tags: python, block

I am having some trouble to write a sub condition within python.
Hope that someone might be able to review my code:

There is the first condition that read GPIO, (24) and the other condition is as if a file exist.
If the file is present, no need to do anything.

Here is my initial code:
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep     
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)     
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)    
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)   
file = "22.gp"


try:
        while True:            
                if GPIO.input(24): 
                print "Port 24 is 1/HIGH/True - LED ON"
                    if os.path.exists(file)
                    print "Already light ON"
                    else:
                    GPIO.output(22, 1)
                    file = open(file, "w+")
            sleep(20)
    else:
            print "Port 24 is 0/LOW/False - LED OFF"
            GPIO.output(22, 0)         
                    if os.path.exists(file):
                    os.remove(file)
                    else:
                    print("sorry, I cannot remove %s file:" % file)
            sleep(0.1)         

finally:                   
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This code gives such of error:

```
print "Port 24 is 1/HIGH/True - LED ON"  
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: ya. browse on indentation error.

Comment: i don't know if u are new in python or not, but why you don't indent after if statement?

Comment: Yeah, I am somehow new in python... is it because of tab used?

Comment: Whitespace is actually important in Python. Spaces/Tabs tell it where a block starts and ends, so after an `if` statement you need to indent the next line in from where the previous one was so Python realises it's a new block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, python doesn't use curly braces or semi-colons, for understanding scope and end of a statement indentation is needed.

```
if GPIO.input(24): 
print "Port 24 is 1/HIGH/True - LED ON"
```

Change this to that(All of the if/else,loops):

```
if GPIO.input(24): 
    print "Port 24 is 1/HIGH/True - LED ON"
```

Using 4 space is a standard. Follow it.

Comment: I have written it inside paranthesis

Comment: thank you very much, figured the changes  - All good; thanks again